# How to sanitize $_GET variables to prevent path injection?

Tags: php, security

What is the best way to sanitize `$_GET['']` request? I want to allow downloading files from one directory only.

```
$baseDir = "/home/html/xy.com/public_html/downloads/";    
$path = realpath($baseDir . $_GET['file']);
```

What is the next step?

Comment: Well you should definitely disallow `..`

Comment: This is all? After that my script is will be secure?

Comment: No, disallow `/` and any other characters that files will not have in them.

Comment: Do you want to allow subdirectories underneath `$baseDir`, or will all requestables files be in that one directory only?

Comment: Final solution: http://d.pr/FPn0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I would do after the lines you have there:

```
if (dirname($path) === $baseDir) {
    //Safe
}
```

http://php.net/dirname

Basically, do a check before sending anything that the file is actually in that one path you support.  Note, you will also have to add your own `/` before the filename (in `$path`) and remove it from your `$baseDir` definition, as `dirname()` won't leave a trailing path separator.

Comment: I must to disable "/", ".." and other characters in the path, or it is not necessary after this? Thank you.

Comment: @Adrian, You should really understand how this works before you proceed.  This script of yours has the potential to be dangerous if you don't.  My method ensures that the path of the file in `$path` is the same path specified in `$baseDir`.  If someone uses `..` or `/`, then those paths won't match anymore.  Therefore, it is safe.  It is important you understand this.  If you were checking more than one directory, the problem gets much more complex.

Comment: +1 for Brad's comment. It is vital that you understand that you need to be extremely paranoid about file system access.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of post-checking that no relative path fragments were present, it's easier to just strip them right away. Just use [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) immediately when you fetch the value:

```
$baseDir = "/home/html/xy.com/public_html/downloads/";    
$path = realpath($baseDir . basename($_GET['file']));
```

That already guarantees that it can't move upwards or downwards from your base directory.

Comment: Thanks, I combined this with Brad's solution. :)

Comment: what if `../` is entered in $_GET?

Comment: @tazotodua What if you read the answer about using `basename()`?

Answer (score 0):

Before you assign the `$_GET` to `$path` you need to sanitize the value.

I recommend using PHP's own sanitize functions ([http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php). Needs to have PHP >= 5.2.0,

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename) and [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/realpath) functions. I found examples like [this](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/php-security-2/) doing `basename(realpath("allowed/" . $filename))`, but it seems to me that this way the realpath would check even for existence of disallowed files. So I would do it three-steps:

```
$tha_basename=basename($_GET["fname"]); /* takes only file name and ext from get */
$tha_realpath=realpath("allowed/" . $tha_basename); /* checks for file existing in the allowed location, if it exists, converts "../" to dir/dir/ */
$tha_basename=basename($tha_realpath); /* finaly this takes only file name and ext from the real location */
```