# How to add domain in front of file_get_contents in PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm new here and had a PHP Coder to some mods to 2 files of mine which were suppose to be able to let the user be able to link directly to the file converted from DOC to IMG on http://NFOPic.com

Here is the Code Edited (you can see edited parts with 'DrTech76') -:

get_image.php

```
<?php
require_once 'include/db.php';
$file_name = $_GET['f'];
if ( empty( $file_name ) || !file_exists( 'uploads/' . $file_name ))
{
    die( 'File not found...' );
}

$sql = "SELECT original_file_name FROM nfo_images WHERE file_name = '" . $file_name . "'";
$rs = mysql_query( $sql );
$file = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs );

$original_file_name = explode( '.', $file['original_file_name'] );
//just get rid of the last, then put back together
array_pop( $original_file_name );
$original_file_name = implode( '.', $original_file_name );

header("Content-Type: image/png");
//start edit 10.07.2014 DrTech76, flow the direct image link through here to keep the actuall location unknown
if(!isset($_REQUEST["dl"]))
{//it's not a request through a direct link, so process as file download, as it was   originally
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $original_file_name . ".png\"");
}
//end edit 10.07.2014 DrTech76, flow the direct image link through here to keep the actuall location unknown
echo file_get_contents( 'uploads/' . $file_name );
?>
```

The other File Edited is the index.php (added input area, should have been text area IMO with a 'select to copy' to copy contents to clipboard) (THIS IS ONLY THE AREA EDITED I'VE ADDED, or else will be too long)

```
<div id="uploaded_image_div" align="center">
            <b>Left Click on the Below Image to Save it to your PC...</b><br /><br />
            <div id="title" style="font-weight:bold;"></div>
            <br />
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="" /></a>
            <br />
            <?php
            //start edit 10.07.2014 DrTech76, direct link containers, styling is done  through css/style.css
            ?>
            <div id="direct_link">
                <label for="link">Direct link to this image</label><br />
                <input id="link" readonly onfocus="$(this).select()" />
            </div>
            <?php
            //end edit 10.07.2014 DrTech76, direct link containers, styling is done through css/style.css
            ?>


            <br />
            <br />
```

**Can someone please help me fix this error, as you can see from the NFOPic.com index page the actual domain name is not showing up - though I need it so if I upload this to another domain (a new domain picked out when BETA is released) it will work with any domain, instead of just putting http://nfopic.com/ in front of the code - THANKS IN ADVANCE GUYS!**

Comment: Do you want to add your site on the pdf you generate

Comment: you have XSS hole in your code

Comment: A png is not a text file, you can't just add text to the beginning of it. You will need to use PHP GD or imagemagick to manipulate the image.

Comment: @Peter I see a possible SQL injection problem, where is the XSS hole? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @Hudixt - No site has nothing to do with PDF's, it turns TXT, NFO & DIZ Files into PNG Image Files (obviously there are more files than the "problem codes" I've uploaded that do all this work!

Comment: @Peter - Sorry I'm not a PHP/mySQL coder I have no clue what a XSS Hole is, is it an easy fix? There are 3 more .php files on the backend to do the conversion and another to hold the bitmap font used. How would I go about fixing this problem, 3 Coders have seen this Code, the original GPL Coder, a 2nd who added TXT & DIZ Conversion & 3 DtTech76 who just edited the above 2 files to add a 'View Direct Image' function so I'm not very confident in finding somebody who can fix this XSS problem.

Comment: @Popnoodles I'm aware of this LOL, this web service has been in production for along time, have you even tried the site? It uses a Bitmap Font for the actual 'Image' Text - Upload a Text File and see the conversion process in action mate! (before you make judgement)... Also, this is just the latest parts edited that are suppose to show a Direct Link URL after conversion process finished, however its not showing the domain name infront of the get_image.php file name which is what Im trying to fix with this question! UPLOADED is only s mall section of whole script, the "Problem I'm Trying 2 Fix'

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro can you please help me fix this injection problem please. As you know this is only a snippet from the index.php file and the whole get_image.php file, which is responsible for adding the 'Direct Image Link' to the index.php page after a file is converted to PNG (using the PHP back-end ie. other files are responsible for this part of things), but this SQL injection risk bothers me, can u pls elaborate on this and maybe find a soltion or show me where it is so I can get it fixed somewhere please? Thx 4 seeing what others overlooked. Want 2 see CHECK script for me? if it fancies u?

Comment: @Popnoodles here is a working TXT to PNG the site has made. http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=image_141094911798.png&dl **IT SEEMS THE DOMAIN NAME IS NOW SHOWING UP INFRONT OF THE get_image.php in the "Input' are on the Index File on a Different system using FireFox... WHAT THE HELL IS GOING ON HERE. What is coded, should be coded right?** Working on Epic Privacy Browser, Chrome, IE, FF & whatever else? What a nightmare-ish problem this is.

Comment: @Peter - The 'converted' counter relies on how many 'file' names are added to the DB to count how many files have been converted to PNG, though this used to be over 36,000 about 8wks ago, and out of nowhere it reset, and was having db.php problems (errors showing on index.php - can see in error.log) it seems this was my fault, uploading an older db.php file with wrong login info, though WOULD an injection explain reset to ZERO, as all the IMG Files are still in the host's folder & ALL the 'file names' are still in the DB, the count is just 'OFF'.Hmmm. Another problem tahts beyond surface probs

Comment: you should escape any user input before using it in SQL by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

I dont know other part of your code, but for example if attacker will create query like `?f=';DROP TABLE nfo_images;--` you will lose all your data.

also there is another vulnerability, if attacker will pass parameter like ?f=../index.php he will be able to download your php scripts

Comment: Adding to what Peter said: you should consider replacing `mysql_` functions (that are deprecated as of PHP 5.5) and using `mysqli_` or PDO instead (with which you can use parameterized queries)

Comment: I can confirm there is vulnerability on your website. I was able to obtain your db passwords, login "nf....ay", password "at...ew"...

Comment: I was about to write the same. You should never trust user input, and you may want to use `.htaccess` to prevent users from reading folders that they shouldn't (e.g.: the include folder), although I don't know if that would have helped in the vulnerability reported by Peter.

Comment: "have you even tried the site?" No. A question posted here should be all that is required to diagnose and resolve the issue.

Comment: @Peter, are you upto putting these fixes into place, there is not much to this whole PHP script. But every other coder has not seen this, and u noticed right away. What would it take for you to plug this up? Thanks for the input, I guess putting the db.php online for everyone to see was a mistake. If I change the name of the db.php file, will this secure this part of the DB login vulnerability?

Comment: @Popnoodles Yep, and it has nothing to do with PDF's nor was it mentioned anywhere... Do you hve a solution for what code to put infront of the get_image.php edited code so it will show the domain infront no matter what browser is being used please or no matter what domain?

Comment: @Peter or let me know where this string should go on the File(s) above so I have a better understanding and then I can pass onto a coder who is willing to plug this script up 5 PHP files in total btw. most are small like the get_image.php file (whole file) posted above.

Comment: The problem is you will give user any file he asks using `$_GET['f']` parameter. This is how I get your db.php file: http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=../include/db.php you always need to filter user data, in this case you should need to filter `$_GET['f']`. I don't know where did you get your "coders" but this is very basic stuff. if you go to http://nfopic.com/include/db.php you are "safe" but you should deny access to internal files anyway

Comment: @Peter is there an easy fix (line(s) of code I can add to this file to make the $_GET['f'] safe so it only it can only get files from the /uploads folder or something like that? Without putting you out too much. I know we are off the original question long ago, but it never really got answered anyhow, and in most browsers it adds the domain infront of the get_image.php in the <imput> field on the index.php page, but is there something I can put infront of -:

Comment: @Peter - oops, continued, infront of ---->              header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $original_file_name . ".png\"");                                             So it puts the domain name of whatever domain the script happens to be installed on, no matter what? Just as a backup cos for some reason it was not showing up I think it was on GreenBrowser IE mode -a)  Is this possible to do  b) do you think it was just some glitch? but what (I ask myself), as u said this little script of mine needs some touching up before getting out of alpha. Hope can learn a 'lil here 2

Comment: So there is still a problem here? Besides the fact, that you still have a XSS vulnerability in your code.

Comment: @PatrickG -  Well the original question/solution has not been answered, you can see the details in the last 2 comments I made to 'Peter' - can you help?

Comment: You said, some "coders" have seen the code and didn't even recognized the flaws? Probably they aren't Web Developers.

You definitely have to review your whole code for any vulnerabilities.

First use `PDO` or the `mysqli` functions to do any Database related stuff. With the prepared statements of PDO (e.g. `$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE filename = ?")` where the ? will be replaced by bound values and also escaped) you will have fixed the injection problem.

To fix the path problem, you will have to check the given `$_GET['f']` and if it's trying to get out of the `uploads` folder

Comment: @theiNaD although I understand everything you are saying about PDO & mysqli (researching for 2 days) I don't quit get what you mean about fixing the 'path problem' How do I check the given $_GET[f] & see if it's trying to get out of the /uploads folder? Could you explain this to someone who is not a "coder" please? Basically I want to FIX whatever it is you are saying here, HOW DO I DO THAT (IN CODE?) & how would I add a 'Code' 2 the  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $original_file_name . ".png\""); So it puts the domain of watever domain the script is installed on pls?

Comment: The problem is, we (Stackoverflow) are not here to code your application.
I'll give you some ideas:
First you can check the `$file_name` variable for `..` etc. which allows the "attacker" to move into a parent folder. You can fix it by replacing it with `str_replace` etc. so that the given path `../index.php` wouldn't end up as `uploads/../index.php` and instead looks like `uploads/./index.php` or something similar.
Just googled and found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8159368/724292 maybe you should check it out if you don't have any subfolders (in uploads) this should be an easy one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are quite some things to do with this script.

**1) Get rid of the XSS and the SQL injection vulnerability:**

Right now, you are checking if the file exists, which isn't completely wrong, but doesn't do the job for you:

```
$file_name = $_GET['f'];
if ( empty( $file_name ) || !file_exists( 'uploads/' . $file_name ))
{
  die( 'File not found...' );
}
```

Since Peter already told you, that you are allowing people to download your SQL Server access data by inserting http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=../include/db.php into the browser, I'll just assume you understood the basic problem.
`file_exists` just checks if the file is available on the server, which is true for your `include/db.php` file. So the Interpreter jumps over the IF and continues with the execution. Since you are already using the DB, we are going to use it, to determine if the file really exists. We'll get to that in a sec.

`mysql_query` isn't safe at all (SQL injection)! You'll have to use PDO or MySQLi for SQL queries (I'm using PDO for demonstation):

```
$prep = $db->prepare("SELECT original_file_name FROM nfo_images WHERE file_name = ?");
$prep->execute(array($file_name));
$res = $prep->fetchAll();
if(count($res) == 0){
  die( 'File not found...' );
}
$original_file_name = explode('.', $res[0]["original_file_name"]);
// ... and what else you want to do with the file name
```

You can read more about it here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Now we should have closed both vulnerabilities by using this way (Assuming the upload doesn't allow wrong interacting with the DB -> you need to check the `generate_image.php`).

**2) Your problem with adding the Domain:**

I didn't quite get what your problem was with that, so feel free to comment and ask further questions, if I am not answering the right way.

**-** You can get the current domain, by calling `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. This should output something like: nfopic.com (I don't know where you would want to add that though).

**-** If you meant that the domain name in the `input` field is wrong, you can change that in your `js/nfo.js` file. There is the line:

```
$('#uploaded_image_div #link').val('http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=' + validate[1]);
```

The `http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=` part is hardcoded, so you would have to insert it any other way.

**-** If you meant to add the domain name to the imagename, which the user can download, You would have to redirect your image with a `.htaccess` file, so you can request the real image name `image_234234.png`.

**3) The rest of the homepage:**

Since there are so many vulnerabilities and mistakes in this part of the website, there have to be some in `generate_image.php`. The check for the filetypes (txt, nfo and diz) are done in JS. The problem with that is, that you can work around them and upload any other filetype, if there isn't some check in PHP too. This leads us to another vulnerability -> a SHELL script could be uploaded (simple PHP file) and your files could be modified from an attacker.

**FINALLY:**
The whole homepage might be insecure. There are definitely some modifications that need to be done. 
And again, if I didn't answer your starting question, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: b4 I get in2 the complete detailed Answer u gave (MUCH MUCH THANKS & APPRECIATION BTW) & Someone who is speaking 2 me in lay terms for a change is a relief (Thx 4 that 2) :-) Solutions/Answers that do not involve some code to replace other code or examples such as u have done, go over my head & as u see over & over ppl tell me I hav a problem but not how to fix it. OK, say changed the same of the db file and it's location & edited all files that ask for db file 2 new Name/Location would this fix the Vulnerability option of accessing the DB file? If not WHY NOT? & How would I pls? THX

Comment: Every php script has a config or db file, so if the whereabouts & name isnt known does this fix this issue? & how would I fix it so nobody can access the db file? - I thought it best just now to address each of the issues you presented 1 by 1, if thats OK?
AGAIN THANKS SO MUCH FOR TAKING THE TIME. Oh, the TXT, NFO, DiZ File vulnerability u talked about, its PHP, but it has some code if you try to upload anything that is not in the 'allowed' file list it gives an error. I'll upload that code next to see if you think it's secure enough or can I add something to make it better.

Comment: For part **2)** of your Answers, no this isn't what I meant. For a while on a certain browser the domain was not showing up in the input field for the link to the PNG, it started with get_image.php? etc w/out the domain in front of it (4 whatever reason, I'm not sure as code has not been changed before or after now its working fine on all major browsers) But I'm worried certain specialized browsers will have this effect in future (it was EpicBrowser a Privacy browser or GreenBrowser) my point is, is there a code I can add infront that stands for the domain its hosted on that would solve this?

Comment: You're welcome =) Well, you could change the db file location to a unknown folder (`include` is a pretty common name). But you could still download the `get_image.php` file, and see the path to the file there -> http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=../get_image.php (rename it to something.txt and you should see the code). You really should do this with a DB query (as I stated in the anwer) or just link to the file in the folder itself (link to nfopic.com/uploads/myfile.png). I'll answer the other questions after work.

Comment: If you show me your upload file, I can have a look at it. And for your initial question: there is no reasonable explanation, that the link would be showing up without the domain up front. `http://nfopic.com/get_image.php?f=` is hardcoded, which means, that any browser would either show up all or none of it. If you could confirm me, that the browsers you mentioned are doing it right now, I can have a look at that too, but I seriously doubt that -> because it simply makes no sense. I hope I answered why "hiding the db file" wouldn't work already in my last comment.